# Bow to know how much amount my wallet sent with Bticoin-core API

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, api

I have updated bitcoin-core from version 0.16 to 0.17 and found that there is no way to see how much amount I sent only (excluding received amount) from my wallet.

With bitcoin-core version 0.16, I set account "rec" for receiving addresses only and segregate incoming and outgoing amounts. Then

`bitcoin-cli getbalance ""`

showed the amount sent from my wallet.

But I do not know how to see sum of amounts sent with bitcoin-core version 0.17. Is there anyway to see it?